# AzureAD B2C Sign In Custom Policy returns "Invalid username or password."

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Using the SignInAndSignUp custom policy, I can sign up and reset password successfully, I am logged in after Sign Up, but for some reason I can't Sign In.

**I have the ApplicationIds set in TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml**

Here is some data I got from AzureAD B2C VS Code Application Insights Extension:

Exceptions: **Invalid username or password.**
Validation technical profiles: **login-NonInteractive**

```
{
  "Key": "Exception",
  "Value": {
    "Kind": "Handled",
    "HResult": "80131500",
    "Message": "Invalid username or password.",
    "Data": {
      "IsPolicySpecificError": false
    }
  }
}
```

login-NonInteractive in TrustFrameworkBase.xml:

```
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Local Account SignIn</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="login-NonInteractive">
      <DisplayName>Local Account SignIn</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ProviderName">https://sts.windows.net/</Item>
        <Item Key="METADATA">https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
        <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token</Item>
        <Item Key="response_types">id_token</Item>
        <Item Key="response_mode">query</Item>
        <Item Key="scope">email openid</Item>
        <!-- <Item Key="grant_type">password</Item> -->

        <!-- Policy Engine Clients -->
        <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
        <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="username" Required="true" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="grant_type" DefaultValue="password" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="scope" DefaultValue="openid" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="nca" PartnerClaimType="nca" DefaultValue="1" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="oid" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" PartnerClaimType="tid" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" PartnerClaimType="upn" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="localAccountAuthentication" />
      </OutputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

login-NonInteractive in TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml:

```
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Local Account SignIn</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
     <TechnicalProfile Id="login-NonInteractive">
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="client_id">I have it set, but removed for question</Item>
        <Item Key="IdTokenAudience">I have it set, but removed for question</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="client_id" DefaultValue="I have it set, but removed for question" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="resource_id" PartnerClaimType="resource" DefaultValue="I have it set, but removed for question" />
      </InputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is always because you did not follow this process accurately.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#register-identity-experience-framework-applications

And
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#add-application-ids-to-the-custom-policy

You can use my setup tool instead to automate the process. Just delete the two application registrations (proxyief and ief) first. https://aka.ms/iefsetup.

Comment: Ahh, I removed the apps and re-created them, still the same issue, I've triple checked everything, not sure what to do anymore

Comment: Delete the apps and use my setup tool. Wait a minute before testing a sign in.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that. Thanks

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much. I deleted the apps, and run this. Then uploaded my own custom policies, and it worked.

Comment: https://aka.ms/iefsetup this thing is not working anymore.
I am still facing 'Invalid username or password' issue. Have tried like 6 times from scratch.